# my implementation of gradient boosting

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, adaboost

Currently I am reading "Machine Learning in Action" by Peter Harrington. I tried to use some of the book's code for AdaBoost to implement Gradient Boosting. I used pseudo-code from *"The Elements of
Statistical Learning"* by *Trevor Hastie et al*. and *Friedman’s Gradient Boost algorithm*. I spent not little time and efforts implementing the algorithm in python so I would be tremendously grateful if you could point me to where my mistake is.

```
stumpReg(), buildstumReg(), gradBoostPredict()
```

are helper functions adapted from the book. I used *absolute error loss* as a loss function
 Here's the code:

```
"""
stumpReg
Description: Creates a simple stump by taking mean values of target 
        variable(classLabel) in each of 2 branches
Parameters: 
dataSet - training data
classLabel - target for the prediction (dependent variable)
dim - dimension of the feature vector
thresh - threshold value
ineq - inequality('less than', 'greater than') 
Returns:
retArr - the resulting array after splitting
select - boolean array that defines values in 2 branches
"""
def stumpReg(dataSet,dim,thresh,ineq):
    retArr = ones((dataSet.shape[0],1))
    if ineq == 'lt':
        select = dataSet[:,dim] <= thresh
        retArr[select] = mean(dataSet[:,-1][select])
        retArr[~select] = mean(dataSet[:,-1][~select])
    else:
        select = dataSet[:,dim] > thresh
        retArr[select] = mean(dataSet[:,-1][~select])
        retArr[~select] = mean(dataSet[:,-1][select])
    return retArr, select

def buildStumpReg(dataSet,classLabel):
    dataSet = mat(dataSet); classLabel = mat(classLabel).T
    m,n = shape(dataSet)
    stepNum = 10.0; bestClassEst = mat(zeros((m,1))); bestStump = {}
    minError = inf
    for i in range(n):
        minRange = dataSet[:,i].min(); maxRange = dataSet[:,i].max()
        stepSize = (maxRange - minRange) / stepNum
        for j in range(int(stepNum)):
            for ineq in ['lt','gt']:
                thresh = (minRange + float(j) * stepSize)
                classArr, selected = stumpReg(dataSet,i,thresh,ineq) 
                errArr = err(classLabel,classArr)
                totalErr = errArr.sum()
                if totalErr < minError:
                    minError = totalErr
                    bestClassEst = classArr.copy()
                    bestSelect = selected.copy()
                    bestStump['dim'] = i
                    bestStump['thresh'] = thresh
                    bestStump['ineq'] = ineq
    return bestStump, minError, bestClassEst, bestSelect

def findMinGamma(sub,x,y):
    gamma = inf
    for error in [sub.max(), sub.min(), sub.mean()]:
        if err(x+gamma,y).sum() > err(x+error,y).sum():
            gamma = error
    return gamma

def TreeBoost(dataset, classLab, numIt=19):
    N, numFeat = dataset.shape # N is the number of training entries
    weakPredictors = []
    stump, error, classEst,sel = buildStumpReg(dataset,classLab.T)
    weakPredictors.append(classEst.T)
    gradLoss = zeros((N,1))
    for m in range(numIt):
        gradLoss = sign(classLab.T - classEst) #gradient of the absolute error loss function
        bestFittedStump,fittedError,f,selected = buildStumpReg(dataset,gradLoss) # fitting a tree to target *gradLoss*
        f=mat(f)
        left = f[selected]
        yLeft = gradLoss[selected]
        right = f[~selected]
        yRight = gradLoss[~selected]
        subLeft=yLeft-left
        subRight=yRight-right
        gammaLeft = findMinGamma(subLeft,left,yLeft)
        gammaRight = findMinGamma(subRight,right,yRight)
        gamma = selected*gammaLeft + ~selected*gammaRight
        bestFittedStump['gamma'] = gamma
        weakPredictors.append(bestFittedStump)
        f += multiply(f,gamma)
    return f,weakPredictors

def gradBoostPredict(testData, weakPredictors):
    testData = mat(testData)
    m = testData.shape[0]
    pred = mat(zeros((m,1)))
    classEst = weakPredictors[0]
    for i in range(1,len(weakPredictors)):
        classEst, select = stumpReg(testData,classEst, weakPredictors[i]['dim'], \
                                    weakPredictors[i]['thresh'], weakPredictors[i]['ineq'])
        classEst += multiply(classEst,weakPredictors[i]['gamma'])
        classEst = classEst.T
    return pred
```

Something is very wrong because the predictions are quite far from actual values. I would be immensely glad to give any more clarifications if needed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is not a free debugging software... you should add the debugging messages to your code, and as it is fully deterministic - trace it step by step on some simple, 1 dimensional example with pen and paper in order to find out where your program goes wrong.

Comment: @lejlot thanks for the comment. Can you at least confirm, please, whether I am on the right track or not?

Comment: I am not familiar rnough with the implementation of the adaboost from above books to give you some general pointers. I would spend much more time trying to figure out the way it is implemented, then you would spend on debugging, so it is unreasonable to even start, if you did not try to analyze it with pen and paper till now.

Comment: @DavidKartashyan have you find out any solution for your problem?